# Put Comma separated values in Collecton Object

Tags: java, collections

I have a query String which receive as `January, February, March`

I would like to split the string by comma and would put the String in `HashMap`, so that when I retrieve I would like to get and do a null check the String as `January, February, March`

How can I do this?

Comment: You can do it using split method of String. BTW, why HashMap? Why not List?

Comment: What do you mean to say by putting it in the HashMap? Are you going to store all the comma seperated values into the Map?Then ArrayList will be fine I guess.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari I will always have maximum of three values, so I would like to assign or put names for each value and fetch by names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You can use the following code to store the months in a hash map.   

 import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;
    import java.util.Set;
    import java.lang.String;

    public class strings {
        public static void main(String [] args){
            String text = "jan,feb,march,april";
            String[] keyValue = text.split(",");
            Map<Integer, String> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
            for (int i=0;i<keyValue.length;i++) {
                myMap.put(i, keyValue[i]);
            }
             Set keys = myMap.keySet();
                Iterator itr = keys.iterator();

                Integer key;
                String value;
                while(itr.hasNext())
                {
                    key = (Integer)itr.next();
                    value = (String)myMap.get(key);
                    System.out.println(key + " - "+ value);
                }
        }
    }

The out put will be-
0 - jan
1 - feb
2 - march
3 - april


Further you can perform the check that you want
```

Comment: Pratik Singal, Thanks for this, I have tried calling as `key.getInteger("1")`, but is null. I would like to call by some name, that's why I was looking for HashMap. Any way I can call by 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function:

```
String[] monthsArray= yourString.split(",");
```

Then you can convert it to a HashSet like:

```
Set<String> months = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(monthsArray));
```

Or to a list:

```
List<String> months = Arrays.asList(monthsArray)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar-

```
    final String input = "January, February, March, ...";
    final String[] months = input.split(",");
    final List<String> monthList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(String month : months) {
        monthList.add(month);
    }
```

You can even convert from array to list directly, check Collections Framework API.

EDIT: `monthList=Arrays.asList(months)`

Comment: You cannot further assign a value in final List<String> monthList inside for loop.

Comment: Only elements are added, reference is not changed ;)

Comment: @Sudhanshu What is the best way to check whether `monthList.get(0)` is null or empty?

Comment: @Sudhanshu Is this the best approach  `if(monthList.get(0).equals("")){` ?

Comment: You can use String's isEmpty() method as well, provided you are sure that its not null.